# Can I navigate to other route/component outside ReactComponent code? How?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

> I'm now using `React@v17.0.2` and `react-router-dom@v5.2.0`.

I know I can do this:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function SomeComp (){
  const history = useHistory()
  function handleSomeEvent() {
    history.push('....')
  }
  return <.../>
}
```

But when sending http request, there would be errors like `not login` or `session expired`.
And my http logic might look like:

```
export default {
  get(url) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( res => {
        if(res.error == 'not login')
          // i want to navigate to login page here
        return res
       })
  },
  post() {
    // ...  
  },
  delete() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Because this is **outside component**, so I can't use `useHistory`.

> I'm not good at English, if I don't express it clearly, please tell me.
> Any help(grammar, misuse of words) is appreciated.

Comment: What does "navigate outside components" mean? Are you wanting to navigate out of your app to an external URL? Or do you mean to just *some* other route/component within your app? See [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few options for accessing a history object:

1. On the `res.error == 'not login'` you can throw an error and let the calling code then handle the rejected Promise (*which it should already be doing*), and handle the imperative navigation in the component.

   ```
   get(url) {
     return fetch(url)
       .then( res => res.json() )
       .then( res => {
         if(res.error == 'not login') {
           throw res.error;
         }
         return res;
        });
   }
   ```

   Then in the component that presumably has access to the `history` object:

   ```
   fetchData = async () => {
     try {
       await get("some url");
     } catch(err) {
       if (err === 'not login') {
         history.push("/login");
       }
     }
   ```
2. Create a custom history object, passed to `Router` and imported for use by code outside components.

   Create and export a custom history object

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

   const history = createBrowserHistory();

   export default history;
   ```

   **Note:** If you are using a HashRouter then create a hash history:

   ```
   import { createHashHistory } from "history";

   const history = createHashHistory();

   export default history;
   ```

   Import `history` and pass to `Router` component

   ```
   import { Router } from "react-router";
   import history from "../path/to/history";

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Router history={history}>
       <App />
     </Router>,
     node
   );
   ```

   Import `history` and invoke in fetch allback

   ```
   import history from "../path/to/history";

   ...

   get(url) {
     return fetch(url)
       .then( res => res.json() )
       .then( res => {
         if(res.error == 'not login') {
           history.push("/login");
         }
         return res;
        });
   }
   ```
3. Pass the `history` object to `get`.

   ```
   get(url, history) {
     return fetch(url)
       .then( res => res.json() )
       .then( res => {
         if(res.error == 'not login') {
           history.push("/login");
         }
         return res;
        });
   }
   ```

   Then in the component that presumably has access to the `history` object:

   ```
   const history = useHistory();

   fetchData = () => {
     try {
       await get("some url", history);
     } catch(err) {
       // handle errors
     }
   ```

Comment: I think the second is more suitable for me. But I'm using the ```HashRouter```. It seems that I can't use this solution when using ```HashRouter```. Any advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Aliar I see. I added an update/note for creating a hash history object. Please also ensure you are using the plain `Router` component ***and not*** the `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter` components.